# Can we have a dog as pet as long as we don't touch its saliva?

Tags: halal-haram, pets, dogs

A friend of mine have a dog pet. i asked her if it's allowed in islam and she said it's okay as long as we don't touch the saliva. 
She also means that petting dog is allowed.

```
Is it true? is there any Ayat Al-qur'an to prove this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sole purpose of having a dog is to keep it as a pet, then it's *haraam* to do so.  The Prophet said:

> "Whoever keeps a dog, neither as a watch dog nor as a hunting dog, will
>   get a daily deduction of two Qirat from his good deeds."

[(Sahih al-Bukhari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/72/6)

The prohibition has nothing to do with dogs being impure or that the angels don't enter the home.  None of these assumptions are valid because we know dogs are pure animals and the angels not entering the homes were angels of revelation and not all angels.

Again, it's *haraam* to keep a dog as a pet due to the reduction of good deeds.  And Allah commanded us to do good deeds.

Answer (score -2):

Refer to [this article by John (Yahya) Ederer](http://www.suhaibwebb.com/islam-studies/faqs-and-fatwas/mans-best-friend-the-islamic-view-on-dogs/) where he makes some great points about dogs in islam and why we can or can not keep them as pets. I found this article very informative and brings up some great points.

The Quran does not forbid Muslims from having dogs as pets or touching their saliva. In fact, the Malaki madhab allows muslims to do so. There reall is only one piece of evidence which suggests that it may not be in our best interest to keep dogs as pets and thats the hadith with Angel Jibraeel saying that angels will not enter the home where a dog is present. Again, this by no means suggests that it is HARAM to do so.

Allahu Alam